# Microsoft graph API not returning all matching users

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph API with below query to get users.API is not returning all results.

```
$"users?$select=mailNickname,mail,id&$filter=Startswith(mailNickname,'{alias}')

$"users?$select=mailNickname,mail,id&$filter=Startswith(mailNickname,'{alias}')
```

I should get all users matching with the alias I am providing an input to API.

Comment: Could you add details on the response ? Do you have some kind of paging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging ?